# How to create a function in PHP that sorts an array based on one of its keys

Tags: php, arrays, function, sorting

I have the following array:

```
$class = array(
        'e1' => array('nume' => 'Nitu', 'prenume' => 'Andrei', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
        'e2' => array('nume' => 'Nae', 'prenume' => 'Ionel', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 27),
        'e3' => array('nume' => 'Noman', 'prenume' => 'Alice', 'sex' => 'f', 'varsta' => 22),
        'e4' => array('nume' => 'Geangos', 'prenume' => 'Bogdan', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
        'e5' => array('nume' => 'Vasile', 'prenume' => 'Mihai', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 25)
);
```

What I would like to do is to create a function that can sort through this array based on one of its keys, for example I want the function to sort and output all the males ('sex' => 'm') from the array.

I have managed to do this with:

```
foreach ($class as $val) {
    if ($val['sex'] == 'm')
    echo $val['nume'].' '.$val['prenume'].'<br/>';
}
```

But I want to create a function of my own that can do just this, which would help me a lot and give me more insight on how functions work and how they should be done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking not for *sorting* your array, but for *filtering* it - feel the difference.

In PHP, there's [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to do this. If you want to create flexible function, you can act like this:

```
function filterArray($data, $key, $value)
{
   return array_filter($data, function($row) use ($key, $value)
   {
      return $row[$key]==$value;
   });
}

$class = array(
        'e1' => array('nume' => 'Nitu', 'prenume' => 'Andrei', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
        'e2' => array('nume' => 'Nae', 'prenume' => 'Ionel', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 27),
        'e3' => array('nume' => 'Noman', 'prenume' => 'Alice', 'sex' => 'f', 'varsta' => 22),
        'e4' => array('nume' => 'Geangos', 'prenume' => 'Bogdan', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
        'e5' => array('nume' => 'Vasile', 'prenume' => 'Mihai', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 25)
);

$result = filterArray($class, 'sex', 'm');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
function array_sort($array,$search_key,$search_val){
    $re_array = array();
    foreach($array as $value){
        if($value[$search_key] == $search_val)
            $re_array[] = $value;
    }
    return $re_array;
}
$class = array(
        'e1' => array('nume' => 'Nitu', 'prenume' => 'Andrei', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
        'e2' => array('nume' => 'Nae', 'prenume' => 'Ionel', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 27),
        'e3' => array('nume' => 'Noman', 'prenume' => 'Alice', 'sex' => 'f', 'varsta' => 22),
        'e4' => array('nume' => 'Geangos', 'prenume' => 'Bogdan', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
        'e5' => array('nume' => 'Vasile', 'prenume' => 'Mihai', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 25)
);
$data = array_sort($class,'sex','m');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write the function yourself and don't use the existing [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function, you could do the following:

```
findAll($array, $key, $value)
{
    $result = array()
    foreach ($array as $val) 
    {
        if ($val[$key] == $value)
        {
            $result[] = $val;
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like `findAll($class, "sex", "m")`. It will return an array of results that you can display as you already did:

```
$filteredArray = findAll($class, "sex", "m")
foreach ($filteredArray as $item) 
{
    echo $item['nume'].' '.$item['prenume'].'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.You can user [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function.

```
function filterSex($row){
  return $row['sex'] == 'm';
}

$newArray = array_filter($class, "filterSex");
```

2.Or you can iterate through array by yourself:

```
function filterSex($array){
  $result = array();
  foreach ($array in $row){
    if ($row['sex'] == 'm'){
      $result[] = $row;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
$newArray = filterSex($class);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function output($key, $criteria){
    foreach ($class as $val){
        if ($val[$key] == $criteria)
            echo $val['nume'].' '.$val['prenume'].'<br/>';
    }
}
```

You can call this function by passing the parameter. For example: `output('sex', 'm')`. Assume that `$class` is global variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $class = array(
          array('nume' => 'Nitu', 'prenume' => 'Andrei', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
          array('nume' => 'Nae', 'prenume' => 'Ionel', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 27),
          array('nume' => 'Noman', 'prenume' => 'Alice', 'sex' => 'f', 'varsta' => 22),
          array('nume' => 'Geangos', 'prenume' => 'Bogdan', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 23),
          array('nume' => 'Vasile', 'prenume' => 'Mihai', 'sex' => 'm', 'varsta' => 25) 
);

$object = json_decode(json_encode($class), FALSE);
```

after that you can do your foreach compare like so:

```
foreach ($object as $val) 
{
if ($object['sex'] == 'm')
echo $object['nume'].'  '.$object['prenume'].' SEX is : '.$object['sex'].'<br/>';
}
```

oops just saw that this post was over a year old...perhaps someone may find it useful.