# PHP : Search all record from array with specific value

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays.

```
    $a = ( 
           array( 'number' => $value, 'name' => $name ),
           array( 'number' => $value, 'name' => $name ),
           array( 'number' => $value, 'name' => $name ), 
         );
    $b = ( 
           array( 'number' => $value, 'address' => $address ),
           array( 'number' => $value, 'address' => $address ),
           array( 'number' => $value, 'address' => $address ),
           ...
         );
```

Now, lets say for a particular record in $a having 'number' = 10. Is there a way in PHP that I can extract all the addresses from $b having 'number' = 10. I am using foreach at the moment but it takes too long as I have more than 5000 records in $a and more than 20000 records in $b.

```
    $result = array();  

    foreach ($a as $tempA) {
      $result[]['number'] => $tempA['number'];
      $result[]['name'] => $tempA['name'];
      $address = array();

      foreach($b as $tempB) {
        if($tempB['number'] !== $tempA['number'])
          continue;
        $address[] = $tempB;
      }
      $result[]['addresses'] = $address;
    }
```

So the result will be like this:

```
   $result = (
    ('number' => 10, 'name' => 'xyz', 'addresses' => array(<contains all addresses with number 10>) )
   )
```

Comment: Can you show your current approach with foreach to give a better understanding of the data and expected result? The pseudo code is not quite clear to me.

Comment: and where are all these data stored?

Comment: Edited the question. I hope it clears my question.

Comment: @ponciste Data is stored in mongoDB database

Comment: so isn't better to do it with a query?

Comment: I am getting data from 2 files and have to store in db. So I have to create PHP script that reads data from file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a function in PHP that sorts an array based on one of its keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273799/how-to-create-a-function-in-php-that-sorts-an-array-based-on-one-of-its-keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that only involves iterating each array once which should significantly reduce the processing time needed:

```
$a = array(
    array('number' => 1, 'name' => 'Bob'),
    array('number' => 2, 'name' => 'Sue'),
    array('number' => 3, 'name' => 'Jim'),
    array('number' => 4, 'name' => 'Cal'),
);

$b = array(
    array('number' => 1, 'address' => 'Address 1A'),
    array('number' => 1, 'address' => 'Address 1B'),
    array('number' => 1, 'address' => 'Address 1C'),
    array('number' => 2, 'address' => 'Address 2A'),
    array('number' => 2, 'address' => 'Address 2B'),
    array('number' => 4, 'address' => 'Address 4A'),
    array('number' => 4, 'address' => 'Address 4B'),
    array('number' => 4, 'address' => 'Address 4C'),
    array('number' => 4, 'address' => 'Address 4D'),
    array('number' => 4, 'address' => 'Address 4E'),
);

// Create array $c to index address records by key
$c = array();
foreach ($b as $item) {
    $key = $item['number'];
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $c)) {
            $c[$key] = array();
        }
        $c[$key][] = $item['address'];
}

// Now loop through $a creating the address on array $a by accessing $c by key
foreach ($a as $index => $item) {
    $key = $a[$index]['number'];
    $a[$index]['addresses'] = $c[$key];
}

// The result now lives in array $a
var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

First I thinks you need  rebuild you array $b to next format :

```
$newB = array('numberValue'=> array('address 1', 'address, 2', '...'));
```

rebuilding :

```
$newB = array();

foreach($b as $v)
{
     $newB[$v['number'][] = $v['address'];
}
```

second find all address by number :

```
forerach($a as $v){
    $newB[$v['number']]; 
    // get all address   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `array_*` functions:

```
function findAddressesByNumber($number, $names, $addresses){
    $found_names = array_values(
        array_filter($names, function ($v) use ($number) {
            return $v['number'] == $number;
        })
    );
    if (!count($found_names)) return false;
    $found_addrs = array_map(
        function ($v) { return $v['address']; },
        array_filter($addresses, function ($v) use ($number) {
            return $v['number'] == $number;
        })
    );
    return array(
        'number' => $number,
        'name' => $found_names[0]['name'],
        'addresses' => $found_addrs
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The selected solution can be made twice as fast by removing unnecessary tests and intermediate variables.

It is so fast that the first limit encountered will be the script memory limit, so this is just of academic interest.

```
define ("MAX_NAMES", 50000);
define ("ADDR_PER_NAME", 4);

function create_arrays ()
{
    $n = array();
    $a = array();
    for ($i = 0 ; $i != MAX_NAMES ; $i++)
    {
        $n[] = array ( 'number' => $i+1, 'name' => str_shuffle("abc") );
        for ($j = 0 ; $j != ADDR_PER_NAME ; $j++)
        {
            $a[] = array ( 'number' => $i+1, 'address' => str_shuffle("abcdefghi"));
        }
    }
    shuffle($a);
    shuffle($n);
    return array ($n, $a);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

list ($a, $b) = create_arrays();

$start = microtime(true);
foreach ($b as $item) $c[$item['number']][] = $item['address'];
foreach ($a as $index => $item) $a[$index]['addresses'] = $c[$a[$index]['number']];
echo "short version done in ".(microtime(true)-$start)."s<br>";

$a=$b=$c=null; // to avoid hitting memory limit

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

list ($a, $b) = create_arrays();

$start = microtime(true);
$c = array();
foreach ($b as $item) {
    $key = $item['number'];
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $c)) {
            $c[$key] = array();
        }
        $c[$key][] = $item['address'];
}

foreach ($a as $index => $item) {
    $key = $a[$index]['number'];
    $a[$index]['addresses'] = $c[$key];
}
echo "long version done in ".(microtime(true)-$start)."s<br>";
```

output:

```
short version done in 0.70000100135803s
long  version done in 1.5700018405914s
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you need to use to use some kind of Algorithm, because speed  is critical for you.

There are alot of sorting algorithm. I would advice you to use Quicksort, because it very fast in sorting; And in this case sorting  the array will save us  a lot of time.

```
function quicksort($seq) {
    if(!count($seq)) return $seq;
    $pivot= $seq[0];
    $low = $high = array();
    $length = count($seq);
    for($i=1; $i < $length; $i++) {
        if($seq[$i] <= $pivot) {
            $low [] = $seq[$i];
        } else {
            $high[] = $seq[$i];
        }
    }
    return array_merge(quicksort($low), array($pivot), quicksort($high));
}
var_dump(quicksort($a));
```

This is sorted very quickly, then the actual matching is quicker. After this you can loop through the array and make the string comparisons